# Заменить %20 в xfsearch DLE

Tags: php, dle

Как заменить %20 в xfsearch на - в ссылке поиска по доп.полю

Comment: это формат кодированого URL, может не заменить а воспользоваться URLDecode или что-то такое? Действительно "заменить"? А если попадётся + %2F %3D тоже будете заменять?

Answer (score 0):

static public function slugify($text)
            {

```
            $slug = preg_replace('/\W/', ' ', $text); //remove remaining nonword characters
            $slug = preg_replace('/[-\s]+/', '-', $text);

            return $slug;
        }
```

Comment: весьма странное решение. А если будет %2F, например то что делать?